# angular 8 application UI not rendering in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, angular8, compatibility, polyfills

Hi I have an application in angular8, which is working fine in all the browser but not in IE. i have tried many solutions available online but it didn't worked out so far, here is my

polyfills.ts :-

```
         * BROWSER POLYFILLS
         */

        /** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
        import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
        import 'core-js/es6/object';
        import 'core-js/es6/function';
        import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
        import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
        import 'core-js/es6/number';
        import 'core-js/es6/math';
        import 'core-js/es6/string';
        import 'core-js/es6/date';
        import 'core-js/es6/array';
        import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
        import 'core-js/es6/map';
        import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
        import 'core-js/es6/set';

        /** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
        import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

        /** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
        // import 'core-js/es6/reflect';


        /** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
        // Used for reflect-metadata in JIT. If you use AOT (and only Angular decorators), you can remove.
        import 'core-js/es7/reflect';


        // import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.

     

   

        /***************************************************************************************************
         * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
         */
        import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.
```

browserList file

```
            # This file is currently used by autoprefixer to adjust CSS to support the below specified browsers
        # For additional information regarding the format and rule options, please see:
        # https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#queries
        # For IE 9-11 support, please uncomment the last line of the file and adjust as needed
        > 0.5%
        last 2 versions
        Firefox ESR
        not dead
        IE 9-11
```

tsConfig.ts

```
      {
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": "./",
      "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "declaration": false,
      "module": "es2015",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "target": "es5",
      "typeRoots": [
        "node_modules/@types"
      ],
      "lib": [
        "es2017",
        "dom"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Kindly help me out, how can i make it work in Internet explorer.

Answer (score 0):

By default in version 8, if we use `ng serve` or `ng test`, it will generate a single ES2015 build which cannot run in IE 11.

According to [this link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14455), there're two ways to have ES5 code during serve which make angular 8 app work in IE11.

1. Disable differential loading completely. (**Not recommended**)

   You can turn differential loading off by changing the target from **"es2015"** to **"es5"** in your **tsconfig.json**.
2. Have multiple configurations for serve.

   Create a new tsconfig tsconfig-es5.app.json next to tsconfig.app.json with the below contents:

   ```
    { 
     "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
     "compilerOptions": { 
     "target": "es5"   
      }
    }
   ```

   In your angular.json add two new configuration section (es5 node) under the build and serve target to provide a new tsconfig.

   ```
    "build": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
        "options": {
            ...
    },
    "configurations": {
    "production": {
        ...
    },
    "es5": {
        "tsConfig": "./tsconfig-es5.app.json"
    }
    }
    },
    "serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "options": {
        ...
    },
    "configurations": {
    "production": {
    ...
    },
    "es5": {
        "browserTarget": "<your application name>:build:es5"
    }
    }
    },
   ```

   [Note] Change the application name to your owns.

   Besides, the browserslist file content as below:

   ```
    > 0.5%
    last 2 versions
    Firefox ESR
    not dead
    IE 9-11 # For IE 9-11 support, remove 'not'.
   ```

   You can then run the serve with this configuration using the below command:

   ```
    ng serve --configuration es5
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this following code, it works in my case.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```